# Why opencv videowriter can't open?

Tags: c++, opencv

I try to save my Mat to vector; and merge it to another function. But I fail, I got an error about "could not open video file for writing". How can I solve it? Here's my code

```
void COPY_THREAD(MAIN_FORMAT *ts, vector<cv::Mat>& Abuffer, vector<cv::Mat>& Bbuffer)
{
//.....
   Mat Roi_img = Mat org_img(Rect(LINE_X_START, YP - (resize_height), IMAGE_X_RANGE, resize_height));
   if (AbufferUsed == AU) // Abufferused == 0
    {
        Abuffer.push_back(Roi_img.clone());
        numFrames++;
    }
    else
    {
        Bbuffer.push_back(Roi_img.clone());
        numFrames++;
    }
    org_img.release(); //2023.04.04 added
    Roi_img.release();
//....
}
void SAVE_THREAD(MAIN_FORMAT *ts, vector<cv::Mat>& Abuffer, vector<cv::Mat>& Bbuffer)
{
   int codec = cv::VideoWriter::fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G');
   VideoWriter videoWrite;
   videoWrite.open(TEMP_AVI.str(), codec, 10, Size(1920, 720), true);
   if (!videoWrite.isOpened())
   {
       printf("Could Not Open Video File For Writing\n");
   }
   else
   {
        if (BufferUse == AU)
        {
            for (const auto& frame : Abuffer)
            {
                //printf("Frame Width %d, Height %d, Channels %d\n", frame.cols, frame.rows, frame.channels());
                videoWrite.write(frame);
            }
            Abuffer.clear();
            Abuffer.shrink_to_fit();

        }
        else
        {
            for (const auto& frame : Bbuffer)
            {
                videoWrite.write(frame);
            }
            Bbuffer.clear();
            Bbuffer.shrink_to_fit();
        }
        videoWrite.release();
    }
}

int main() {
    vector<cv::Mat> Abuffer;
    vector<cv::Mat> Bbuffer;
    thread t6(COPY_THREAD, &main_data, ref(Abuffer), ref(Bbuffer));
    thread t7(SAVE_THREAD, &main_data, ref(Abuffer), ref(Bbuffer));
//...
}
```

This is part of my code. I checked the Mat size is correct.(resize_height is 720, width is 1920)
why I can't open videowriter?

Comment: [mre] please. make sure you got your paths right. *test* that. chances are, it's not an opencv issue.